# What are the Maven dependency parameters for the Java Gradle API?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Gradle plugin in Java. In order to use the IDE for developing (especially code completion), I need to add to the `pom.xml` file of the project the dependency information for the `org.gradle.api.*` classes.

Where can I find it?

I tried [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.gradle.api), but couldn't find it there.

Comment: The Gradle project does not publish all core libraries to a publicly-available repository (e.g. you might need `org.gradle.gradle-model` which is not published). There's no guarantee that you'll be able to build a Gradle plugin with Maven.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko is it still a thing? How in that case one supposed to resolve this dependencies while working in IDE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this artifact after a longer search: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gradle/gradle-core/2.2.1

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
  <artifactId>gradle-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The artifact is available in following repository: http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-remote/

```xml
<repository>
  <id>Spring Source Libs</id>
  <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-remote/</url>
</repository>
```

Add the repository to the repositories section in your pom.xml as well as the artifact as dependency. I tested it with a Maven project in my Eclipse workspace - the org.gradle.api.* classes are available and I can also browse the gradle-core sources.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the official Gradle Releases repository in a Maven pom try this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
        <artifactId>gradle-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
        <artifactId>gradle-tooling-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
        <artifactId>gradle-base-services</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
        <artifactId>gradle-base-services-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.gradle.org</id>
        <url>https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
dependencies {
  //we will use the Groovy version that ships with Gradle:
  compile localGroovy()

  //our plugin requires Gradle API interfaces and classes to compile:
  compile gradleApi()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question. I can successfully build the plugin with Gradle, but I want to be able to build it with Maven so that IntelliJ Idea can resolve Gradle API classes and support code completion.

Comment: He's looking for `pom.xml` dependency.

Comment: Sorry, i slipped through that... Why would you write a Gradle plugin in Maven? :S IntelliJ has Gradle support as well.

Comment: *IntelliJ has Gradle support as well*: Then how can I make IntelliJ Idea recognize the classes `org.gradle.api.*`? I have already a Maven plugin, which does code quality checks. Now I want to create a Gradle plugin, which does the same checks in Gradle. See https://github.com/teamed/qulice .

Comment: By Gradle support i meant you can create a Gradle project, add the block i posted, and IntelliJ should compile the project.

Comment: Why don't you just download the [sources JAR from gradle.org](http://gradle.org/downloads) e.g. `gradle-2.2.1-src.zip` and attach it to your project?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are reading this in 2016 (and maybe later).

The artifacts are available in the [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter): [org.gradle:gradle-core](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.gradle%3Agradle-core), no need to add any "custom" `repositories`.

So, all you need to do is:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.14.1'
    // compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, as of Summer'19 the most recent artifact are published in following repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.gradle:gradle-core:5.5.1"
}
```

Comment: Only up to version `6.1.1` at the moment :(

Comment: This is sad. I'm currently searching for `gradle-core-7.5.1`, but it's not included in https://repo.gradle.org/ui/native/libs-releases-local nor in https://repo.gradle.org/ui/native/libs-releases - the highest version is still `6.1.1`.